# Determine the messages-widget to display validator message in JSF (Primefaces)

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, validation, message

In my JSF-page i have a similar situation like this:

```
<h:form>
    ...
    <p:messages id="messagedId" for="messagesWidget" autoUpdate="true" />
    <p:pickList validator="pickListValidator" ... />
    ...
</h:form>
```

The "for"-Tag is very important and can not be removed, because i use this tag to determine the target message-widget from the backing bean.

But how is it possible to determine where the pickList validator message should be shown (in this case "messagesWidget")?

---

I could use

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
FacesMessages msg = FacesMessage(FacesMessages.SEVERITY_ERROR, "short", "long");
context.addMessage("messagesWidget", msg);
```

inside the validator and additionally throw a ValidatorException, but in my opinion this could not be the best solution.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use built-in validator you can give p:pickList an id and add another p:messages component with "for" attribute set to pickList`s id. Then this message component will show validation errors for pickList only.

Comment: But in this case I would have two p:messages components directly behind the other fulfilling the same task. Is there not a possibility two combine those p:messages?

Comment: Then you can combine by specifying for="pickListId messagesWidget".

Comment: I tried this but it seems like only one component is allowed. Primefaces user guide says: "Name of associated key [...]" (not keys...)

Comment: Well if p:messages allows only one component in for attribute you must have multiple p:messages.

Comment: I am not happy to hear this, but thanks for your help!